# Error: 'AddRange' is not a member of 'System.Array'

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

I have no idea why I'm getting this error.
This is my code.

```
        Dim openshells As New OpenFileDialog
    openshells.Title = "Find your Shells"
    openshells.ShowDialog()
    Try
        Dim abc As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openshells.FileName)
        Dim pqr As String() = abc.Split(vbNewLine)

        shells.items.AddRange(pqr)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    FlatStatusBar1.Text = shells.items.Count
End Sub
```

VB.net.
I get the error 'AddRange' is not a member of 'System.Array' for this shells.items.AddRange(pqr)
Think you can help!?

"shells" is a listbox BTW.

Answer (score 0):

this is your solution:

```
 Dim openshells As New OpenFileDialog
    openshells.Title = "Find your Shells"
    openshells.ShowDialog()
    Try
        Dim abc As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(openshells.FileName)
        Dim pqr() As String
        pqr = abc.Split(vbNewLine)

        shells.items.AddRange(pqr)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    FlatStatusBar1.Text = shells.items.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a foreach loop:

```
For Each item As String In pqr
    shells.items.add(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If shells is indeed a ListBox then your code should work.  However, if it is a ListView, instead, then you will indeed get an error with your code. In that case something like this should work:

```
    shells.Items.AddRange((From s In pqr
                              Let item = New ListViewItem(s)
                              Select item).ToArray)
```

One other possibility is, you have another object named shells.items which is an array.